# How to create external table for hbase

Tags: hbase, hive

I am able to create external tables in hive of HBase, now i have a requirement to create an external table which is having variable columns, which means the columns in HBase are not fixed for the particular table, the no of columns and can be created dynamically at the time of data insertion, what should be the approach for handling such kind of situation.

Summery : How to create external tables in hive when the no of columns are not fixed in HBase table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you think that would work?

Comment: I got some solution which i will post here too which will help others if needed

 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE shashwat(key int, value map<string, string>)
   > STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
   > WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,demo:")
   > TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "hbase_shashwat");

Answer (score 7):

1. Create table in Hbase shell

   `create 'hbase_2_hive_names', 'id', 'name', 'age'`
2. Load data into Hbase (the input file must be in HDFS)

   `export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$(/usr/local/hbase/bin/hbase classpath);$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar /usr/local/hbase/hbase-0.94.1.jar importtsv -Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,id:id,name:fn,name:ln,age:age hbase_2_hive_names /var/data/samples/names.tsv`
3. Create external table in Hive shell

   `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hbase_hive_names(hbid INT, id INT,  fn STRING, ln STRING, age INT) STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,id:id,name:fn,name:ln,age:age") TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "hbase_2_hive_names");`

Answer (score 2):

Step1: **Login to HBase Shell**

```
hbase shell
```

Step2: **Creating HBase table**

```
hbase(main):001:0> create 'hbase_emp_table', [{NAME => 'per', COMPRESSION => 'SNAPPY'}, {NAME => 'prof', COMPRESSION => 'SNAPPY'} ]
Created table hbase_emp_table
Took 1.5417 seconds
=> Hbase::Table - hbase_emp_table
```

Step3: **Describing the HBase table:**

```
hbase(main):002:0> describe 'hbase_emp_table'
Table hbase_emp_table is ENABLED
hbase_emp_table
COLUMN FAMILIES DESCRIPTION
{NAME => 'per', VERSIONS => '1', EVICT_BLOCKS_ON_CLOSE => 'false', NEW_VERSION_BEHAVIOR => 'false', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', CACHE_DATA_ON_WRITE => 'false', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING =>
 'NONE', TTL => 'FOREVER', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', CACHE_INDEX_ON_WRITE => 'false', IN_MEMORY => 'false', CACHE_BLOOMS_ON_WRITE => 'false',
PREFETCH_BLOCKS_ON_OPEN => 'false', COMPRESSION => 'SNAPPY', BLOCKCACHE => 'true', BLOCKSIZE => '65536'}
{NAME => 'prof', VERSIONS => '1', EVICT_BLOCKS_ON_CLOSE => 'false', NEW_VERSION_BEHAVIOR => 'false', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', CACHE_DATA_ON_WRITE => 'false', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING =
> 'NONE', TTL => 'FOREVER', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', CACHE_INDEX_ON_WRITE => 'false', IN_MEMORY => 'false', CACHE_BLOOMS_ON_WRITE => 'false',
 PREFETCH_BLOCKS_ON_OPEN => 'false', COMPRESSION => 'SNAPPY', BLOCKCACHE => 'true', BLOCKSIZE => '65536'}
2 row(s)
Took 0.1846 seconds
```

Step4: **Inserting data to HBase table**

```
put 'hbase_emp_table','1','per:name','Ranga Reddy'
put 'hbase_emp_table','1','per:age','32'
put 'hbase_emp_table','1','prof:des','Senior Software Engineer'
put 'hbase_emp_table','1','prof:sal','50000'

put 'hbase_emp_table','2','per:name','Nishanth Reddy'
put 'hbase_emp_table','2','per:age','3'
put 'hbase_emp_table','2','prof:des','Software Engineer'
put 'hbase_emp_table','2','prof:sal','80000'
```

Step5: **Checking the HBase table data**

```
hbase(main):012:0> scan 'hbase_emp_table'
ROW                                             COLUMN+CELL
 1                                              column=per:age, timestamp=1606304606241, value=32
 1                                              column=per:name, timestamp=1606304606204, value=Ranga Reddy
 1                                              column=prof:des, timestamp=1606304606269, value=Senior Software Engineer
 1                                              column=prof:sal, timestamp=1606304606301, value=50000
 2                                              column=per:age, timestamp=1606304606362, value=3
 2                                              column=per:name, timestamp=1606304606338, value=Nishanth Reddy
 2                                              column=prof:des, timestamp=1606304606387, value=Software Engineer
 2                                              column=prof:sal, timestamp=1606304608374, value=80000
2 row(s)
Took 0.0513 seconds
```

Step6: **Login to Hive shell using either hive or beeline**

```
hive
```

Step7: **Create a Hive table**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hive_emp_table(id INT, name STRING, age SMALLINT, designation STRING, salary BIGINT) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,per:name,per:age,prof:des,prof:sal") 
TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "hbase_emp_table");
```

Step8: **Select the Hive table data**

```
hive> select * from hive_emp_table;
INFO  : OK
+--------------------+----------------------+---------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------+
| hive_emp_table.id  | hive_emp_table.name  | hive_emp_table.age  | hive_emp_table.designation  | hive_emp_table.salary  |
+--------------------+----------------------+---------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------+
| 1                  | Ranga Reddy          | 32                  | Senior Software Engineer    | 50000                  |
| 2                  | Nishanth Reddy       | 3                   | Software Engineer           | 80000                  |
+--------------------+----------------------+---------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------+
2 rows selected (17.401 seconds)
```